# Google Maps not working on tab Ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I create tab on Ionic project. When i would access to Google map from another url Tab, it's not working but when i access it directly it works.

Comment: Check these post if useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719011/config-angular-google-maps-with-ionic-framework/34722232#34722232, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410064/google-maps-on-deviceready-problems/34411505#34411505, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735180/google-maps-in-modal-not-showed-after-two-times-open-ionic/34743291#34743291

Comment: Thank u :)) but  Both of them use google maps on a normal  page not withiin a tab , my problem is that google map is displayed when i access to the tab from tab url of its state but when i access to the tab from another tab url and then move to the google maps tab , it can t be displayed and i have no error message !

Comment: No, there are 3 links, and the third (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735180/google-maps-in-modal-not-showed-after-two-times-open-ionic/34743291#34743291) has a CodePen example with a map in a second tab...

Answer (score 0):

First the Ionic part:
The tab showing the map is:

Ionic calls refreshMap() when the user selects the tab.
refreshMap() is:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.refreshMap = function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.refreshMap_();
        }, 1); //Need to execute it this way because the DOM may not be ready yet
    };

    $scope.refreshMap_ = function() {
        var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        reattachMap(map,div);
    };
})
```

I've implemented reattachMap() looking at the Map.init() method:

```
function reattachMap(map,div) {
    if (!isDom(div)) {
        console.log("div is not dom");
        return map;
    } else {
        map.set("div", div);

        while(div.parentNode) {
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
        div = div.parentNode;
        }

        return map;
    }
}

function isDom(element) {
    return !!element &&
    typeof element === "object" &&
    "getBoundingClientRect" in element;
}
```

And that's about it, now when the user switches back to the map tab, it will be there.

Please refer this.
(https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/256/#issuecomment-59784091)